# Get value from input box with js

Tags: javascript, input, box

I have no idea how to get value from input box. Right now when I click BET button it just subtracts 100, I want to achieve so when I enter the value in the text box and hit bet it'll subtract the value which I've entered from the balance. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value=0 name="betAmount">
    <button class="betBTN">BET</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
document.querySelector('.betBTN').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var toAdd = document.querySelector('div').textContent - 100;
      document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = "";
      document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', toAdd);
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried?  This should be a quick Google query.  https://www.google.com/?q=Get+value+from+input+box+with+js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `100` with

```
document.querySelector("input").value;
```

This line will get the value of `input` element

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
document.querySelector('.betBTN').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var toAdd = document.querySelector('div').textContent - document.querySelector("input").value;
      document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = "";
      document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', toAdd);
    });
});
```

```html
Balance: <div>1000</div>
    <input type="text" value=0 name="betAmount">
    <button class="betBTN">BET</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re talking about the entered value, then the following would do the job:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="betAmount"]').value;
```

All input elements, whether they are HTML `input` or `textarea` or `select` etc have a `value` property which is the actual value of the user data.